# Trouble loading from XML file

Tags: java, xml

I have a major problem. We can call this application "boat club system" and its a assignment in a UML course.  But the problem that is really bothering me is that i can't load the "Member" Objects back to the Arraylist that is used when Exporting and Importing the objects.

I got some help with this by a friend, but the Importing won't work.
This is the Error i get when trying to import.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at boat.Controller.SystemController.readFromSystem(SystemController.java:288)
at boat.Controller.SystemController.<init>(SystemController.java:26)
at boat.View.Console.<init>(Console.java:17)
at BoatMain.main(BoatMain.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

The problem is pointed on this specific line:

```
member.setMemberId(Integer.parseInt(element.get(i).getAttribute("memberId").getValue()));
```

The link to the whole application. 
https://github.com/mjuu/boat/tree/master/src

The System controller class looks like this. 
BTW, i am thinking of splitting up this class to more like System controller and Member controller for a more High Cohesion/Low coupling design. But only when i get the Import working correctly..

I don't know why it doesn't work. The member id is a INTEGER at first, but when exported its converted to a String. When imported it converted to a Int again. So I'm wondering if its something wrong there..

Would really appreciate help so i could continue.
System Controller

```
public void readFromSystem () {

    File file = null;
    Builder builder = null;
    Document doc = null;

    try {

        file = new File(filePath);
        builder = new Builder();
        doc = builder.build(file);

        Element root = doc.getRootElement();

        Elements members = root.getChildElements();


        for (int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++) {

            Elements element = members.get(i).getChildElements();
            Member member = new Member();

            member.setMemberId(Integer.parseInt(element.get(i).getAttribute("memberId").getValue()));
            member.setPersonId(element.get(0).getValue());
            member.setName(element.get(1).getValue());

            memberList.add(member);

            if (members.get(i).getChildElements().size() == 3) {

                Elements boats = element.get(2).getChildElements();

                for (int j = 0; j < boats.size(); j++) {

                    Boat b = new Boat();

                    b.setBoatId(Integer.parseInt(boats.get(j).getAttribute("boatId").getValue()));
                    b.setBoatType(Integer.parseInt(boats.get(j).getChildElements().get(1).getValue()));
                    b.setBoatLength(boats.get(j).getChildElements().get(2).getValue());

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print("Could not read from the system");
    } catch (nu.xom.ParsingException e) {
        System.out.print("Parsing was unsuccessful!");
    } 
}
```

Comment: `"I get a NullPointerException i think"` -- know or know not, there is no "think".

Comment: This should never be in your code: `catch (NullPointerException e) {....}` You should never catch NPE's. You should fix them instead so that they don't happen.

Comment: re `" I'm going to see if i can get the error and post it as a comment here."` -- Please post error message as an edit to your question. Also and again, get rid of that catch block I've indicated above as it's not helping you, but rather it's obfuscating your error so you can't find it since it causes you to lose the line number that causes the exception.

Comment: Yes Sry. I have removed that catch. I have posted the error i get in the console now.

Comment: If this were my problem, I'd try to debug it in a small program, first one that does nothing but reads in the XML file as text and then prints it out in the console, just to see if file reading is working. If that works, then I'd try to parse the data as XML, to see if that is working OK. Often the key to debugging is to "divide and conquer".

Comment: Okey. So the best solution would be to extract that readSystem() and make a another small program and see if it is able to read from the XML file ? + another one that can write to the file ? I know the writing to the file is working, but I'm really sure about the importing

Comment: `element.get(i).getAttribute("memberId")` is most likely null

Comment: No, it's not a solution but a way to try to isolate your errors, to make it easier to debug and **find** a solution.

Comment: But i don't understand fully. Why is      element.get(i).getAttribute("memberId") most likely null ? I have a "1" as attribute for the memberId in the actual xml file. And the writing itself works when i try it individual

Comment: Haven't found my problem yet ;( F*uck